# How to UV-Map for a OpenGL Game

Tags: texturing, uv, opengl

I hope to find some answers here to my problem.

For an OpenGl Game, i want to have some "good" textures, that are equal in display size.

[image: Floor]

We designed a building, whereas in the picture above, you can see the floor and its resulting UV-Mapping with "Smart UV Project". Moving along the in the game, the texture quality on the different floor sections should not should not change of course.

Any good advices on that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much follow any UV unwrapping tutorial on the internet for that. Modeling assets is pretty much the same for all the 3D real-time engines out there.

However, I would highly suggest, that you learn how to unwrap properly as soon as possible. "Smart UV Project" doesn't necessarily give the best result and as soon as your modeling skills go beyond the primitives (cubes, cylinders and the like) you want to have more advanced texture maps.

Besides that, I'd highly suggest that you also start with proper material setups and thus with node materials (maybe also with cycles) as soon as possible. You can then bake your materials to texture maps and use them for your game assets. The big advantage here is that you don't need to adjust your UV map to the "direction" your texture takes (e.g. bricks are arranged into a specific direction).

The biggest pitfall when creating 3D game assets is the use of too many materials. Every material needs to be loaded and processed, thus generating CPU and GPU load. Do this many, many times and the FPS of the game will drop. So in the case of a building, it would be advisable to have only one texture map for the walls and the roof. This is also where baking and maybe even the Texture Atlas add-on come in.

Comment: The problem is, we HAVE to use OpenGL with the very super basic Libraries, that do NOT access OpenGL functionalities.

So, this thing with Node Materials is not possible for us, or very painful in  coding afterwards.

I was looking for another option, that is easier work. I already use seams, i used the chessboard, etc.

If there is anything more than in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ha2rFR6qO0
a hint would be very welcomed

Comment: @Andrea - I never said that you should use node materials in OpenGL. There is no way to use Blender node materials outside of Blender. It's just the "modern way" of texturing game assets. You use it in Blender to create advanced materials which you can bake on normal textures.

Comment: Ah, okay got it. Misunderstanding from my side :X